# How can i fetch text from element only

Tags: jquery, ajax

all i want to do is know how to fetch only the text from an element.

html:

```
<h3>i want to grab this text</h3>
```

and how can i add that method for just fetching the text only with no elements to this

jquery & ajax

```
(function(){
    $("#requestsone h3").load( "request.php #totalamountofrequest" );
    console.log("hello there");
})();
```

so the text i want to fetch is `<h3 id="totalamountofrequest">text<h3>` and i want to add only that text to `<h3 id="requestsone>text<h3>`

Comment: I usually just target the element and use `.textContent`

Comment: Rather than `load()`, grab the element with an ajax call, then use a success function to extract the text node.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using jQuery, you can utilize [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$('#totalamountofrequest').text();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("requestsone").innerHTML=document.getElementById("totalamountofrequest").innerHTML;
```